# Single point on multiple line linear graph with Chart.js

Tags: chart.js, stacked-area-chart

I have a multi line linear chart made with Chart.js like this:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

const colors = {
  green: {
    fill: '#e0eadf',
    stroke: '#5eb84d',
  },
  lightBlue: {
    stroke: '#6fccdd',
  },
  darkBlue: {
    fill: '#92bed2',
    stroke: '#3282bf',
  },
  purple: {
    fill: '#8fa8c8',
    stroke: '#75539e',
  },
};

const loggedIn = [26, 36, 42, 38, 40, 30, 12];
const available = [34, 44, 33, 24, 25, 28, 25];
const availableForExisting = [16, 13, 25, 33, 40, 33, 45];
const unavailable = [5, 9, 10, 9, 18, 19, 20];
const xData = [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19];

const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: xData,
    datasets: [{
      label: "Unavailable",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: colors.purple.fill,
      pointBackgroundColor: colors.purple.stroke,
      borderColor: colors.purple.stroke,
      pointHighlightStroke: colors.purple.stroke,
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      data: unavailable,

    }, {
      label: "Available for Existing",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: colors.darkBlue.fill,
      pointBackgroundColor: colors.darkBlue.stroke,
      borderColor: colors.darkBlue.stroke,
      pointHighlightStroke: colors.darkBlue.stroke,
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      data: availableForExisting,
    }, {
      label: "Available",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: colors.green.fill,
      pointBackgroundColor: colors.lightBlue.stroke,
      borderColor: colors.lightBlue.stroke,
      pointHighlightStroke: colors.lightBlue.stroke,
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      data: available,
    }, {
      label: "Logged In",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: colors.green.fill,
      pointBackgroundColor: colors.green.stroke,
      borderColor: colors.green.stroke,
      pointHighlightStroke: colors.green.stroke,
      data: loggedIn,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    // Can't just just `stacked: true` like the docs say
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
      }]
    },
    animation: {
      duration: 750,
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

My problem is that when I go over a point all points on that column activate. 
I want to activate just the single point on the selected line.

So, just to be clear, this is what I have now: [Actual Behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsbqA.png)

And this is what i want: [Expected Behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDhwr.png)

Anyone could help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the hover [interaction mode](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html) option like so:

```
options: {
  hover: {
    mode: 'nearest'
  }
}
```

Working example:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

const colors = {
  green: {
    fill: '#e0eadf',
    stroke: '#5eb84d',
  },
  lightBlue: {
    stroke: '#6fccdd',
  },
  darkBlue: {
    fill: '#92bed2',
    stroke: '#3282bf',
  },
  purple: {
    fill: '#8fa8c8',
    stroke: '#75539e',
  },
};

const loggedIn = [26, 36, 42, 38, 40, 30, 12];
const available = [34, 44, 33, 24, 25, 28, 25];
const availableForExisting = [16, 13, 25, 33, 40, 33, 45];
const unavailable = [5, 9, 10, 9, 18, 19, 20];
const xData = [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19];

const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: xData,
    datasets: [{
      label: "Unavailable",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: colors.purple.fill,
      pointBackgroundColor: colors.purple.stroke,
      borderColor: colors.purple.stroke,
      pointHighlightStroke: colors.purple.stroke,
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      data: unavailable,

    }, {
      label: "Available for Existing",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: colors.darkBlue.fill,
      pointBackgroundColor: colors.darkBlue.stroke,
      borderColor: colors.darkBlue.stroke,
      pointHighlightStroke: colors.darkBlue.stroke,
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      data: availableForExisting,
    }, {
      label: "Available",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: colors.green.fill,
      pointBackgroundColor: colors.lightBlue.stroke,
      borderColor: colors.lightBlue.stroke,
      pointHighlightStroke: colors.lightBlue.stroke,
      borderCapStyle: 'butt',
      data: available,
    }, {
      label: "Logged In",
      fill: true,
      backgroundColor: colors.green.fill,
      pointBackgroundColor: colors.green.stroke,
      borderColor: colors.green.stroke,
      pointHighlightStroke: colors.green.stroke,
      data: loggedIn,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: false,
    // Can't just just `stacked: true` like the docs say
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: true,
      }]
    },
    animation: {
      duration: 750,
    },
hover: {
mode: 'nearest'
},
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```